# Should I use UIDocument to handle PDF files that I have saved to disk?

Tags: ios, swift, pdf

The UIDocument class offers open and close functionality, in a thread conscious manner. Should I use it, or is it overkill?

All I want to do is create and load some pdf files.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your users will be modifying the files in any way, UIDocument seems like a fine approach.

If all you need is the ability to *view* files, then I would recommend WKWebView. A webview is a pretty light-weight approach, and also provides a standard UI that users are accustomed to seeing when viewing pdfs.

Once you've added a webview, your pdf can be loaded into it like this:

```
import WebKit

...

guard let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Sample", ofType: "pdf") else {
   return
}

let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
webView.loadFileURL(fileURL, allowingReadAccessTo: fileURL)
```

(Where "Sample" is the name of the pdf file).